# R, define a function then apply to a list

Tags: r, list, function, reshape

I am trying to write a function (and I am new to R, most of my knowledeges of R were learned form this wedsite, thanks),

I want to apply my function to a list. The list contain some ".CSV" files.

All CSV files in my folder look like the picture below, same structure but with different column numbers.

I want to :

1. based on "Frame" column, delete all the row contain words "T",
   then I got "110*n1" rows data.
2. delete all the column contain ""Flag" words, they are blank column.
3. delete the 1st column. then I have "2*n2" columns.
4. reshape the mulit-column to 2 column data, now I got "110*n3" rows data.
5. repeat "1,2,3,4,...,110" as seires numbers, n times(n=n3), rebind as a column.
6. form "1,2,3,...,n3", each repeat 110 times, make as a colum.
7. export the new table as txt files.

[image]

Here is what I've done so far:

```
T_function <- function(x) {
    data.df <- read.csv(x, skip = 1,header=TRUE, na.strings=c("NA","NaN", " ","*"),
                        dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)
    filename <- substr(x = x, start = 1, stop = (nchar(x)-4))
    data.df[!grepl("T", data.df$Frame),]  
    data.df <- data.df [,-1]
    data.df <- data.df [,colSums(is.na(data.df))<nrow(data.df)]

    splitter <- function(indf, ncols) {
        if (ncol(indf) %% ncols != 0) stop("Not the right number of columns to split")
        inds <- split(sequence(ncol(indf)), c(0, sequence(ncol(indf)-1) %/% ncols))
        temp <- unlist(lapply(inds, function(x) c(t(indf[x]))), use.names = FALSE)
        as.data.frame(matrix(temp, ncol = ncols, byrow = TRUE))
    }

    out <- splitter(data.df, 2)
    list <- 1:110
    from <- which(out$V1 == 1)
    to <- c((from-1)[-1], nrow(out)) 
    end <- c(to/110)
    list2 <- rep(list,length(to/110))

    out$Number <- unlist(list2)
    out$Number <- as.factor(out$Number)
    list3 <- rep(1:end,each=110)
    out$slice <- unlist(list3)
    out$slice <- as.factor(out$slice)

    write.table(x = data.df, 
                file = paste0(filename, "_analysis.txt"), 
                sep = ",",quote=F)
}
```

It seems the function can not add correct "out$Number" and "out$slice".

```
filenames <- list.files(path = "",pattern="csv",full.names = T)

sapply(filenames, FUN = T_function)
```

I am trying to apply my function to all files in list, while it seems beside the 1st files I can't get other files to work.

Could anybody help me find out and salve problems?

Comment: Have you checked out the map function in the purrr package? Check out the purr cheat-sheet

Comment: Hi,@Super_John,, thank you for your advise, I quickly searched the "purr", and I got a lot of  "purrr" wedsite.  I used a folder contain 2 CSV files then tried "library(purrr), map(filenames, T_function)", I got a errror suggestion "[[1]]NULL, [[2]]NULL".